# Detect that a page has been loaded from form submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

I have a search form with the following code:

```
<form id="search_form" action="index.php" method="post">
```

PHP code delivering search results on the same page is triggered by:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
```

I also have javascript on this page that runs on page load (using addEventListener). Since the page is reloaded with the form submission, the script runs again. This is not desired. Therefore, I would like to detect that the form has been submitted and avoid calling the javascript. I could do it if there was a way for Javascript to detect that the $_POST['search'] has been set.

Another way to put it... I would like the initially loading scripts to be blocked if the page is reload is from a form submission.

How may I achieve my aim using vanilla JS?

Comment: You could set a variable to true on form submission (var submitted = true), save it in local storage, and then run the JS inside an if statement that checks for the variable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Don't use a form or `formElement.onsubmit = e=>{ e.preventDefault(); }`. Use the `XMLHttpRequest`, either way.

Comment: If and only if the referrer is set you can check if the referrer is the same page `if(document.referrer == document.URL)`

Comment: Thanks everyone! Obsidian's answer below works great for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the desired JavaScript code inside a PHP conditional that only runs when the `$_POST` value isn't set:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['search'])) {
?>
  <script>
  // Code to run on initial page load
  </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Or, if you prefer to keep it contained within PHP for code clarity:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['search'])) {
  echo "<script>Code to run on initial page load</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is perfect.